# To show that any function $F:(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^v→\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ is of the form $F=\sum_{a∈(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^v} F(a)f_a$.

Tags: group-theory, functions

Fix $a_0=(a_1,a_2,...,a_v)∈(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^v$. Now let us define a polynomial  function $f_{a_0}(x_1,x_2,...,x_v)=\prod_{i=1}^{v} (1-(x_i-a_i)^{p-1})$. Then show that any function $F:(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^v→\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ is of the form $F=\sum_{a∈(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^v} F(a)f_a$. Again deduce from above that every arbritary subset of $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^v$ is a solution set. Here $p$ is a prime number. Please help me to solve it. I am totally confused about the function.

Comment: @FabioLucchini. Sorry its $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^v$ not $C$. I have corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$f_a(x)=
\begin{cases}
1&x=a\\
0&x\neq a
\end{cases}$$
for if $x\neq a$, then $x_i\neq a_i$ for some $i$, hence $(x_i-a_i)^{p-1}=1$.
Thus at least a factor in the product which defines $f_a(x)$ is zero, hence $f_a(x)=0$ as well.

Consequently,
$$\sum_{a\in(\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z)^v}F(a)f_a(x)=F(x)f_x(x)=F(x)$$
because in the sum only the term $F(x)f_x(x)$ is not zero.

Let $S\subseteq (\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z)^v$ be a subset and
$$F=\sum_{a\notin S}f_a$$
so that
$$F(x)=
\begin{cases}
1&x\notin S\\
0&x\in S
\end{cases}$$
Consequently,
$$S=\{x:F(x)=0\}$$
thus $S$ is a solution set.

Comment: Thank you. its very nice. But what about the solution set?

Comment: I added a proof of solution set too.

Comment: thank you. Get it. +1